# document.write javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, symfony, twig

I'm trying to use the `document.write` javascript function to set an external `css` file in my template, but, I want to do this via `Twig` just like this:

```
document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-orange.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
```

But it does not work. Why this `document.write` function is not working? Can I put that `Twig` code in there?

Or what is the best way to pass a `css` route with `Twig` to a `document.write` javascript function?

Sorry if my english is not good. I hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put the particular line of code? Inside a `twig` template or in an external `js` file?

Comment: Inside a twig template

Comment: Then it should work, are you getting any errors? Check javascript console?

Comment: the page and also the console stays blank

Comment: post full template?

Comment: Ok, I have post it in another question because the real problem is bigger and maybe there is anothe way to solve it whithout using the document.ready function. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833005/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-twig-in-this-particular-example) is the link. @DarkBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realize the answer. The problem is that I was using the `document.write()` function inside of `$(document).ready()` function. My mistake was not to post the entire code here so you could see. I didn't know until now that I could not use `document.write()` function inside of the `$(document).ready()` function. Anyway, I want to thank you all for the comments and answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{% stylesheets
    "@ActivosBundle/Resources/public/css/app-orange.css"
    "%kerner.root_dir%/Resources/css/main.css"
%}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I need it inside the document.write js function because I do more things with that in the js function

Comment: I have post it in another question because the real problem is bigger and maybe there is anothe way to solve it whithout using the document.ready function. If you want, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833005/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-twig-in-this-particular-example) link. Thanks for your help. @YamenImadNassif