# How to pass a Javascript variable to Twig in this particular example

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, symfony, twig

The following code is in my `Twig` template and it's for load a `CSS` file or another depending on the theme selected by the user. This works perfectly on a simple `HTML` page but when I try to take this to the `Twig` template of my `Symfony` application I can't find a way to pass the `CSS` route (with `Twig`) to the `Javascript` `document.write` function.

```
<script>
var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
        {};
        var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
        if (themeName)
        {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app-' + themeName + '.css">');
        }
        else
        {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app.css">');
        }
```

In other words: I want to put in the `href` of the `document.write` function what (in `Twig`) it would be this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-red.css') }} "rel="stylesheet" >
```

Where "app-" is invariable and the word "red" is variable depending on the value of the var `themeName`

For that I've try this:

```
<script>
    var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
    {};
    var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
    if (themeName)
    {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app-' ~ themeName ~ '.css') }} ">');
    }
    else
    {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }} ">');
    }
</script>
```

But it doesn't work, It gave me this error:

> Variable "themeName" does not exist in ::base.html.twig at line 1188

I guess it's because `themeName` is not a `Twig` variable but a `Javascript` variable.

I think that the problem here is that I can't pass a `Javascript` variable to `Twig` because `Javascript` is `client-side` and `Twig` is `server-side`.
So, how can I solve this problem? Maybe I'm going through the wrong way, maybe using `Ajax` can be an option, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: As you already thought, you can't pass a `JS` var to `Twig` as `Twig` is already renderd at the serverside before being passed to the client. The only solution here is to switch to `ajax` and change the style that way

Comment: So, How can I do this using Ajax? I've try some examples using ajax too  and doesn't work. Can you give me an example please? Thanks!! @DarkBee

Answer (score 1):

To concat in javascript you have to use '`+`' operator

'`~`' operator is for twig concatenation

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{  asset('bundles/activos/css/app-' + themeName + '.css') }} ">');
```

Comment: I know that, I wrote it with ´+´ operator in the first example I post, and with ´~´ operator in the second. But the problem is how to use the themeName javascript variable in the Twig code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you can't pass a javascript variable to twig you will need to fetch the theme uri by ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) 
                                                                            : {};
                var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
                if (themeName) {                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "url/to/get/theme_uri.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data : {
                            'themeName' : themeName,
                        },
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                            $('#theme-style').attr('href', data.uri);
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

```
<?php
    //... This would be a symfony controller
    public function themeUriAction(Request $request){
        $path = 'bundles/activos/css/app-' . $request->request->get('themeName').'.css';
        return new JsonResponse(array('uri' => $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path)));
    }
    //...
```

---

If you know all the themes at front, you can add them into an array, then you don't need to use ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>

            var themes = {
                {% for theme in themes %}
                    '{{ theme }}': '{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-'~theme~'.css') }}',
                {% endfor %}
            };

            $(function() {
                var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings'))
                                                                            : {};
                var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
                if (themeName in themes) {
                    $('#theme-style').attr('href', themes[themeName]);
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I know all the theme names, but in this last case you are putting a Javascript variable (var themes) into twig code: {% for theme in themes %}. That's not correct. However you gave me an idea: I've try to do this: if (themeName === "blue")
                    {
                        document.write('<link href="{{ asset('bundles/activos/css/app-blue.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >');
                }
And so on for every theme name. But here we're back to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831610/document-write-javascript-function-is-not-working) problem @DarkBee

Comment: With the 2nd example i'm creating a `javascript` variable from inside `twig`. Not the other way around, i'm not passing any javascript to twig. I'm just populating a javascript object with known data from twig

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I misunderstood. But I've try it and its throws this error in the for line: Variable "themes" does not exist in ::base.html.twig at line 1239. I think I can not use that js variable in that way on the twig 'for'

Comment: It's a `twig` variable.. You need to define and create it in your symfony controller and pass it to `twig`

Comment: Oh ok, now I see your point. I'll do that and try!! Thanks for your time ;)